# Macro in Liquid Template language

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I'm using Jekyll, which uses the Liquid Template language. I've used Jinja templating in the past, and it has the concept of a [macro](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros) (just a named function). Does Liquid have something which provides equivalent functionality? If not, is there some Jekyll plugin which will extend Liquid to provide it?

Comment: Since it doesn't look like this exists in Liquid, I've opened up the [issue on Github](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/580).

Answer (score 12):

You can create includes that accept parameters. It's not *quite* a macro but it's what I've used successfully on GitHub Pages.

More details and tips for managing includes and using parameters can be found [in the Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameters-to-includes).

Here's an example:

**_includes/email_link.html**

```
<a href="mailto:{{ include.user.email_address }}"
   title="Email {{ include.user.name }}">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>
</a>
```

**about.md**

```
---
layout: page
title: About
---
{% include email_link.html user=site.users.erik %}
```

**_config.yml**

```
users:
    erik:
        name: Erik
        email_address: erik.gillespie@wizbang.com
```

Comment: There's some gotchas here, as I remember, biggest of which is that includes don't have restricted scope, so variables changed within an include will remain changed after the include.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [Jekyll tags plugins](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags) are made for.

Comment: The GitHub Help about [supported Jekyll plugins](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/) and the GitHub Pages [plugin dependencies](https://pages.github.com/versions/) do not list the Jekyll tags plugin so unfortunately I do not think this solution will work on GitHub Pages.

Comment: So why are you talking about plugins ? Nevertheless, on github pages, @erik-gillespie solution is the one. And thank you for the down vote.

Comment: The OP may not know that the available plugins on GitHub Pages are limited so I thought it pertinent to point out. If the OP *is* using GitHub Pages as the tags suggest then your answer will not work and if tried, will cause a lot of headaches, hence the downvote.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. On my current project, I'm using Github to host but doing the compiling with Travis because I have a few extra steps that Pages won't do. However, having a solution that would work on pages would be nice for future projects.


Moreover, as I understand the tags solution you're suggesting, I would have to create a new custom tag in Ruby for every snippet of HTML I wanted to reuse. This isn't great.