# Is there a way in Jekyll to set a base path for images?

Tags: html, jekyll, blogs

I am creating blog with Jekyll and for the sake of organization I have decided to put the images under the folder: "assets/img/[post name]/". The folders look like this:

```
.
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── BMFW.css
│   │   └── vs.css
│   └── img
│       └── 2021-05-23-Blog-presentation
│           └── test.jpg <--
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── index.html
├── _layouts
│   ├── layout.html
│   └── post.html
├── _posts
│   └── 2021-05-23-Blog-presentation.md
├── README.md
└── script
    └── cibuild
```

Seems that the page.name variable for some reason does not exist (I have checked it with `{{page | inspect}}`) so I use this line to get the name of the post:

```
{{ page.path | replace: ".md","" | split: "/" | slice: -1 | }}
```

That means that if I want to display an image called `test.jpg` I would write:

```
![]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/img/{{ page.path | replace: ".md","" | split: "/" | slice: -1 | }}/test.jpg)
```

The only thing that changes from one image to another is the name of the image. So my question is: is there a way to set a base path, in my case `{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/img/{{ page.path | replace: ".md","" | split: "/" | slice: -1 | }}/`, so I don't have to write the full path over and over again?

The ideal solution would be to just have to write `![]({{media}}/test.jpg)` or similar.

**EDIT 1:**

Just in case it is useful for anybody, what I am doing now is to put this line at the beginning of each blog entry:

```
{% assign media = site.baseurl | append: "assets/media/" | append:  page.path | replace: ".md","" | replace: "_posts/",""  %}
```

So then I can insert images just writing:

```
![]({{ media }}/test.jpg)
```

It is not a solution because I still have to put that line at the beginning of every post but is better than before.

**EDIT 2:**

I have looked to make some custom pluggin in Jekyll but I haven't found a way to get access to the page properties.

Another option was to create a custom tag that inserted the liquid code: `{{site.baseurl | append: "assets/media/" | append:  page.path | replace: ".md","" | replace: "_posts/",""  }}`. The problem with this one is that once the custom tag has ben executed jekyll continues and does not execute the newly inserted liquid code.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repetition in Jekyll, you use [includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/). You could make a `_includes/image.html` file like this:

```html
{% assign media = site.baseurl | append: "assets/media/" | append:  include.post | replace: ".md","" | replace: "_posts/",""  %}
<img src="{{ media }}/{{ include.file }}">
```

and use it like this:

```
{% include image.html post=page.path file="test_1.jpg" %}
{% include image.html post=page.path file="test_2.jpg" %}
```

The only problem is that the included file can't see anything from the file that's not passed as a parameter, so we can't get rid of the `post=page.page` part. However, that's less repetition than with your current solution.

Related: [Macro in Liquid template language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522960/macro-in-liquid-template-language).

Comment: It is a solution to avoid repeating the same line at the begining of each post, but I find more tedious having to write `{% include image.html post=page.path file="test_1.jpg" %}` each time I want to insert an image than copy pasting a longer line at the begining and forgeting about it.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. Jekyll doesn't offer much options in this regard (as far as I know)... I'll leave the answer anyways, in case other person finds it useful.

Comment: I have thought of very weird way of doing it, but I have to test it first to make sure that it is possible. I am using a custom renderer, so I could modify the image markdown tags to add the path during the translation from markdown to html.

Comment: That sounds actually as a good idea. In my opinion, full customization always require some processing by the side of the programmer user.

Comment: I just decided this is a bad Idea. I am changing how the item tag works, that should not be done. But I might create an aditional markdown element, something like `:media:` that is substituted by the actual path.

Answer (score 0):

Would using [static files in Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/) be sufficient for setting the base path for all your image assets?

Add to `_config.yml`:

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "assets/img"
```

All the static files will have base path `assets/img` added to their `file.path` metadata.

Edit:
Here is Liquid snippet on getting the `path` in the `defaults`

```
{% assign defaults = site.defaults %}
{{ defaults[0].scope.path | inspect }}
```

Comment: I would prefer to have my images organized in folders based on the name of the post. As far as I know this solution requires to have all the media in the same folder.